# Creating a calendar event in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-api

I need to create a recurring event in SharePoint calendar. I am able to create non-recurring events. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following resource on MSDN:

[How to: Add a Recurring Event to Lists on Multiple Sites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms434156.aspx)